# Connect-PnPOnline -UseWebLogin Login popup doesn't load when IE Security Level Zone is High

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, sharepoint-online

I have a PowerShell script that is supposed to open the web login popup, since the SharePoint site requires MFA. The script opens the popup, however, it does not load the Microsoft login page content. It loads just a blank page.
[image]

After some hours of troubleshooting, we identified that this is due to the security settings of the Internet Explorer. When the Security Level Setting is set to High in IE, neither the browser nor the popup loads the login page(presume the popup also loads IE).

Due to server restrictions,it is not possible to change the IE settings to a lower level.

Is there any other way of using Connect-PnPOnline in MFA environments/connect to SharePoint Online using MFA
OR is there a way to specify the browser opened by the popup(Edge loads the login page without an issue)?

Answer (score 0):

Found that IE was automatically logged in to our Intranet (SharePoint Online). Logged out of IE, and got the webdialog back again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. What helped for me was running PowerShell under administrative privileges...

[image: Rightmouse click, run as admin]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IE for the MFA (because you're on a server usu) ...

... in the IE, click on the ⚙, then select "Internet Options" settings...

[image: IE Settings Screenshot]

... then select "Security" Tab

... then select "Trusted Sites"

... click on [Sites] button

[image: Sites PopUp in IE Security > Trusted Sites]

... add the following two sites to trusted sites:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com
- https://aadcdn.msftauth.net

... then the MFA popup should work.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you are not able to lower down the IE browser security settings level.

I suggest you add the SharePoint site to the **trusted site list** and configure the **User Authentication** setting may help you to fix the issue.

You can refer to the steps below to add the site to the **trusted site list**.

1. Go to **Tools(ALT + X)**-> **Internet options**-> **Security** tab.
2. Click on **Trusted sites** and click on **sites** button.
3. Insert the **site URL** and click on **Add** button.

[image]

4. Click on the **Close** button.

You can refer to the steps below to configure the **User Authentication** setting.

1. In the **Security** tab click on **Trusted sites** and then click on the **Custom level** button.
2. Scroll to the bottom and find **User Authentication**.
3. Select the **Prompt for username and password** option for **logon** setting.

[image]

4. **Apply** the settings and **restart** the IE browser.

Then after again try to check for the issue.

Comment: Adding it to trusted sites is not a straightforward option, as the Microsoft MFA authentication process contains set of dynamic URls as well. Adding only the login.microsoft.com as a trusted site did not work.

Comment: In that case, you need to lower down the security level of IE to medium-high. This is the only way to overcome the issue as login dialogue is always using IE settings when using PnP Web Login, and there is no parameter in the PowerShell can change to use other browser.

Comment: As I mentioned on my question, it is not possible to lower the IE settings, that is the reason I'm asking the question.

Comment: It looks like at present, this is the only workaround available to avoid this issue. I suggest you try to provide the feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue via feedback hub or using SharePoint online. Thanks for your understanding.